# Java https works but C# doesn't for same request

Tags: c#, java, https, ssl-certificate

I'm converting JAVA program that send `https` POST request to a 3rd party server in internet.

1. Java program run in my PC and it works fine and connect to the server.
2. Then I run the C# program. but server returns `400 Bad Request` response.
3. Then I use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) and compare the content of each HTTP request by JAVA and C# programs, and both contents are exactly same.
4. Here I cannot test using `http` because destination server only allows `https`

So I'm guessing this can be any certificate issue of Visual studio? Anyone have idea about such case?

**Code**

I already posted the code in this question
[Java vs C# HTTP request with JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241191/java-vs-c-sharp-http-request-with-json-data)

Comment: Did you installed certificate in trusted root on your computer ?

Comment: It might help with answers of you showed us the Java code and the C# code.

Comment: @RadenkoZec: You mean for JAVA? or C#

Comment: It is really strange that a certificate error should return 400... I don't believe this is the appropriate return code. There has to be a difference in the generated content. Code please?

Comment: @fge: Java version works fine. Issue is in C# version. I posted the code in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241191/java-vs-c-sharp-http-request-with-json-data

Answer (score 0):

If the problem was occurring in the Java version, I'd dismiss certificates as the cause. In Java, a certificate problem would result in a protocol error exception ... not an HTTP response code.  Similarly sending an HTTP request to an HTTPS port (or vice versa) wouldn't give a HTTP response.

Therefore I suspect that there >>is<< something different about the requests, or the request headers.

The only other alternatives I can think of are:

- the server is giving responses depending on IP addresses, or depending on whether client certs were presented, or something, or
- you are actually talking to a different server or a different proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Try out adding in C# :

```
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

Comment: no luck. here is the error `An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type`